# Deleting lines from file with number

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I have a problem with my c++ project. I've got rooms listed by room numbers and prices, I want to delete a room that I enter it's number. 
Here is my code below; I tried a lot codes but nothing worked. My first delete function was deleting the every line that starts with 1, when I want to delete room 1. 
So I changed it, but now that code only gets the first line of the file to the another file.

Code 1: It only takes the first line to temp file from source.(roomno identified by int)

```
void deleteRoom() {
    rooms room;
    string source;
    string line;
    source = "Room.txt";
    {
        ifstream readFile;
        readFile.open("Room.txt");
        system("cls");
        cout << "Room Number" << setw(13) << "Price" << "\n---------------------------------------------\n";
        while (true) {
            readFile >> room.roomno >> room.price;
            if (readFile.eof()) { break; }
            cout << setw(6) << room.roomno << setw(16) << room.price << " $" << endl;
        }
        readFile.close();
        cout << "---------------------------------------------\n" << "Enter the room number that you want to remove : ";
        cin >> room.roomno;
        ifstream s(source);
        ofstream t("temp.txt");
        while (getline(s, line)) {
            int len;
            if (room.roomno > 0) {
                for (len = 0; room.roomno > 0; len++) {
                    room.roomno = room.roomno / 10;
                    int n = len;
                    int abc = atoi(line.c_str());
                    if (abc != room.roomno)
                        t << satir << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        t.close();
        s.close();
        remove(source.c_str());
        rename("temp.txt", source.c_str());
    }
}
```

Code 2: When I enter the room number that I want to delete it deletes every line starts with this number. For example: When I enter `1`, it deletes every room starts with `1`.)

roomno is identified by string.

```
ifstream s(source); //string line and string source before that
ofstream t("temp.txt");
while (getline(s, line))
{
    int n;
    if (room.roomno.size() == 1)  n = room.roomno.size();
    else if (room.roomno.size() == 2)  n = room.roomno.size() + 1;
    else if (room.roomno.size() == 3)  n = room.roomno.size() + 2;
    else if (room.roomno.size() == 4) n = room.roomno.size() + 3;
    string abc = line.substr(0, n);
    if (abc != room.roomno)
        t << line << endl;
}
t.close();
s.close();
remove(source.c_str());
rename("temp.txt", source.c_str());
```

Comment: Visual Studio has a very good debugger that you really ought to use. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The preferred method to read the file:  `while (readFile >> room.roomno >> room.price)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program can be simplified:

```
rooms  room;
int room_to_delete = 0;
cout << "Enter room to be deleted: ";
cin >> room_to_delete;
while (readfile >> room.roomno >> room.price)
{
  if (room.roomno != room_to_delete)
  {
    t << room.roomno << room_to_delete << "\n";
  }
}
```

In the above snippet, a room is read from the source file.  If the room is not one to be deleted, it is copied to the output file, `t`.

There are other methods, such as reading the entire file into a `std::vector`, modifying the `std::vector`, then writing the `std::vector` to a new file.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but I tried that and now it deletes every line when i enter a number